# Similar PHP form code: First throws error if $_REQUEST is empty, second does not

Tags: php, forms

I'm new to PHP so this might be a simple answer. Hopefully I format this correctly and properly to SO standards (still new to the site.)

I'm working on two sets of very similar code submitting form data and using htmlspecialchars to stop XSS attacks in my very basic beginning PHP book via SitePoint. Simple enough, right.

When working with code set 1, I got an error of undefined index once I changed the form action from

```
<form action="formpost.php" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

I searched SO and found that I needed to check if `$_REQUEST` was empty or not in order for there to be no undefined index and to get rid of that error. If someone can explain that portion to me I'd be very greatful. What perimeters does something need to fall under in order to become an `Index?` *thiking outloud, please don't make fun of me I know I probably sound stupid-->* Is it an 
`Index` because `$_REQUEST` being a `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` is an array and data within an array is `indexed,` `0,1,2,3,etc`.?

I understand `$_REQUEST` could be possibly empty because no `$_REQUEST` has been made (I suppose?) but, being that no script has been activated by entering data into the form, why would it be expecting data to already be in `$_REQUEST`?

**Code Set 1 (thows error [undefined index] unless the script checks if `$_REQUEST` is empty):**
*In this code I'm just allowing the end-user to post their name via the form field or via a string added manually to the url and have it print.*

```
<?php
if( !empty($_REQUEST) )
{
    $firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
    echo 'Welcome to our web site, ' .
        htmlspecialchars($firstname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . ' ' .
        htmlspecialchars($lastname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . '!';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Query String Link Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
              <div><label for="firstname">First name:  
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></label>  
              </div>  
              <div><label for="lastname">Last name:  
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"></label></div>  
              <div><input type="submit" value="GO"></div>  
            </form>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code Set 2 (does not mind if `$_REQUEST` is checked or not):**
*In this code I'm doing the same thing, just if it happens to be my exact name, have it print out a special message.*

```
<?php
    $firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
        if ($firstname == 'Tommy' && $lastname='Loza') 
        {
            echo 'Welcome to our web site web master!';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Welcome to our web site, ' .
                htmlspecialchars($firstname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . ' ' .
                htmlspecialchars($lastname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . '!';
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Conditional Query String Link Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
              <div><label for="firstname">First name:  
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></label>  
              </div>  
              <div><label for="lastname">Last name:  
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"></label></div>  
              <div><input type="submit" value="GO"></div>  
            </form>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully I didn't ask too many stupid questions and this post is formatted correctly. Thanks a lot SO community.

Tommy

Comment: I feel like I #failed a little bit here. My main question after my little Q's in the beginning is, why does code set 1 require to check for $_REQUEST being empty and code set 2 doesn't? Some how adding a conditional statement changes things.

Comment: to prevent XSS attacks this should be `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` this `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>`

Comment: I think your question why everything goes fine in first one but in second one firstly some error and then no erroe when you put something in your form and click the button? Am i right?

Comment: The undefined_index error puts a halt on the page and stops the script, just showing the big ol' error message on a white screen right when the page loads. **Code set 2** runs fine with or without checking for $_REQUEST being empty, now if I were to remove that if statement from **Code set 1**, it'd just throw me that ugly error right on page load.

Comment: Excellent information Pushkar, thank you.

Comment: just try something like `if($_POST) { } `instead of `if(!empty($_REQUEST)){}`

Comment: Thanks for the edit Smith Foto. What characters do I put before and after function names to make them highlighted like code, but inline like that instead of block like code samples?

Comment: @Fresher that did work as well. I'm still new and amazed at how many different ways there were to solve this issue. I took note of all of them. I guess it just required some kind of conditional statement to stop the code from just "running" and requiring that index to be defined immediately? That is my best conclusion from taking in all this info so far. I learned a lot from this post though. Awesome.

Comment: @Pushkar Thanks for that codebit. Very helpful. Didn't tag you in my first thanks.

Comment: @Smith Foto Can you read my above comment for you about that inline vs block code references. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you can't access a REQUEST index unless it exists.

If you don't use the if statement, it's trying to access the index regardless of whether or not it exists. Therefore, if $_REQUEST['firstname'] does not exist, instead of just defaulting to null, it will give the undefined index error, as $_REQUEST is an array.

If you try and use an undefined variable, it'll say "Undefined Variable" instead of "index".

['firstname'] <- This is the index. If this does not exist, it will error.

Checking if it's empty won't necessarily be the only thing either. I'd also be checking to see if firstname and lastname are set, like so:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST) && isset($_REQUEST['firstname']) && isset($_REQUEST['lastname'])){
    //Code here
}
```

Of course you can then check them individually for the ability to throw individual errors depending on whichever one is missing.

--Edit

Also, you can do the following:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    //code
}
```

As by default, it is set to "GET".

Comment: Awesome answer. Without the if statement, is it trying to locate the index automatically because the code is just essentially "running" with out any checks/balances? Where as the if statement is checking the code to say, "Wait, first, check to see if this is true or not, then proceed" and because of that it's not looking for a value for that index immediately? I would feel so great if I grasped that right because I understood your answer fully otherwise. Awesome info on the $SERVER['REQUEST_MEATHOD'] as well. I found a great SO article explaining this in more detail. Good exposure.

Comment: I'm starting to get confused myself now, haha! As to why exactly the second one is working I'm not sure. If you use the 2nd one and refresh the page without entering any form data, it shouldn't work, as the form hasn't been submitted, so getting the $_REQUEST indexes should throw out an error. The reason the first one stops working when you remove the IF statement, is because it's running BEFORE the form is displayed. So if the form is not submitted, it needs to check that the values HAVE been submitted before it can work with them. Does this make sense?

Comment: Basically, since PHP is server-side, it's run before the HTML is. So it's trying to use the data from the form before it displays the form. If there is no data, it will give you an error and then obviously the form will not show on the page. If you check that the data is set, in an if statement, then if the form has not been submitted, the if statement will be false and therefore will not run what is inside the curly brackets. A way of seeing this come to life would be to, after the if statement, add an else{} and stick the form inside that. Then the form would only show if not already sent.

Comment: Dude, awesome. Makes total sense and your second post pointing out that the PHP is running first made it all click. It makes me think of operational PEMDAS but for web technologies and reminds me to keep that in mind. When I get awesome feedback like this from cool people it makes me think SO should allow friends or private messages so people can get in touch with folx who gave great answers. Thanks dude.

Comment: I'm really happy with the great feedback, it's also really nice to have people who are so enthusiastic and grateful for your help, so I appreciate that. I agree, it'd be awesome to have private messaging, but I guess it'd be a lot more traffic for a site of this size.

Answer (score 1):

first give the name of submit button and check if it clicked or not and if you are giving form action on same page so no need to give action just leave it blank watch the code below

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
    echo 'Welcome to our web site, ' .
        htmlspecialchars($firstname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . ' ' .
        htmlspecialchars($lastname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . '!';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Query String Link Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <div><label for="firstname">First name:  
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></label>  
              </div>  
              <div><label for="lastname">Last name:  
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"></label></div>  
              <div><input type="submit" value="GO" name="submit"></div>  
            </form>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Very cool. So if I had multiple forms I could perform different actions by having a unique submit name for each form and checking for an isset($_POST['submit-name']) I presume? Is that right? Thanks again.

Comment: @tommydevs yes it's right multiple forms with submit button's but with button's unique name

Answer (score 1):

As per you question. There are many scenarios in which we need to check empty request.
1. if we have more then one form with submit button. In that case if we do not validate request it is not possible to distinguish which form has been submitted.

2. check box and radio box only submitted if thy selected. So it become necessary to check whether check-box / radio box has been selected or not.

3 if you are using form use always post method and validate with $_POST to prevent from XSS attacks because $_REQUEST works for both $_POST and $_GET.

4. Your second set of code works because text fields always send values when form submitted whether they are remain blank.

I Hope this will help you

Comment: Excellent advice on 1-3 thanks! I don't quite understand answer number 4 though because both sets of code have the same text fields provided? And just the clarify, the error was 'onload' not 'onsubmit'. Thanks again!