# $_REQUEST , Undefined index

Tags: php

i have this php code

```
<?php
include "confiq.php";

$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
echo $username;
?>
```

when i run this code it gives me this error as :

```
Notice: Undefined index: username
```

iam new to php and i did some searching and all of them used isset to eliminate this error ... but i need to define this one because i will use it to get info in profile page 
so , how i can define my username so i can print it on the screen ?!!!

EDIT : 
i tryed the $_GET and it gives me the same error and my include file has no miss writing too 
idk how i can get this to work i need to read the user name and other data from database to display them in profile page but this error is annoying ... plus it didnt show up in the tutorials i saw ... the same code worked perfectly

EDIT:
i also tried this code

```
if (isset($_GET['username']))
{
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $userquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username = '$username'") or die ('cant find the query');
    if (mysql_num_rows($userquery) != 1)
    {
        die ("this profile can not be found");
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $username = $row['username'];
    }
}
else die ("specify username again");
```

and in the profile where i should display the user name it show me the msg (specify username again) 
that means it didnt even go throw the first if in my code 
now what x_x !!

Comment: Where is it supposed to come from? What's the form invoking that script?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024006/similar-php-form-code-first-throws-error-if-request-is-empty-second-does-not

Comment: Should steer clear of `$_REQUEST` and actually use defined `$_GET`/`$_POST` methods

Comment: Yes..Do not get mixed up with `$_REQUEST` at this stage as it will make you confuse as `$_REQUEST` is used for all mixed up so instead use `$_GET /  $_POST` just as @Darren said..!

Comment: Maybe it's intentional, but is your include filename misspelled?  It looks like your include file is spelled with a 'q' instead of a 'g'.